# Why does All Might appear with a yellow aura inside Midoriya's One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Inside Midoriya's One for All, All Might appears with a yellow aura, when other former users of One for All dont appear with an aura at all. Why is this so?

Why does All Might appear with a yellow aura inside Midoriya's One for All?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is because he's the only user of the all for one who is still alive. He already gave the power to Midoriya, so he is no longer a user. But as all the users manifest as a part of the One for All, Allmight does aswell, but partially. Once he dies (if he dies) we will see him "full" inside the one for all.